# Can't get PHP-FPM working so that multiple versions of php can be used

Tags: php-fpm, mod-fastcgi

Server runs CentOs 6.10

Need to use php5 for some websites and php7 for others on the same server so I used the remi repository and enabled the php versions needed.

I've uninstalled mod_php and installed php-fpm and mod_fcgid.

In `/etc/php-fpm.d/www.conf`, I've added:

```
listen = /var/run/php-fpm/www.sock
listen.group = apache
listen.mode = 0660
```

I have created `/var/www/cgi-bin/php.fastcgi` with the following contents:

```
#!/bin/bash

PHPRC="/etc/php.ini"
PHP_FCGI_CHILDREN=4
PHP_FCGI_MAX_REQUESTS=1000
export PHPRC
export PHP_FCGI_CHILDREN
export PHP_FCGI_MAX_REQUESTS
exec /usr/bin/php-cgi
```

Below is an example vhost for a domain:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    # Admin email, Server name and Server alias
    ServerAdmin test@example.org
    ServerName domain.com

    # Document Root settings
    DirectoryIndex index.php
    DocumentRoot /var/www/vhosts/domain.com/httpdocs/
    ScriptAlias /cgi-bin/ "/var/www/cgi-bin/"

    # Logging settings
    LogLevel warn
    ErrorLog /var/www/vhosts/domain.com/log/error.log
    CustomLog /var/www/vhosts/domain.com/log/access.log combined
</VirtualHost>
```

I've basically followed [this guide](https://tecadmin.net/setup-httpd-with-fastcgi-and-php-on-centos-redhat/) but have also tried all sorts of other things from what I've found online, all to no avail.

If I visit a domain on the server, I just get a internal server error or the php is not parsed properly and just output as raw text.

What am I missing in the above configuration?

Answer (score 1):

Using `php-cgi` is old and deprecated, you should use FPM service instead.

See :

- [PHP Configuration Tips](https://developers.redhat.com/blog/2017/10/25/php-configuration-tips/)
- [My PHP Workstation](https://blog.remirepo.net/post/2016/04/16/My-PHP-Workstation)

Notice: PHP-FPM is now the default way in Fedora and RHEL-8 (and thus in CentOS 8, when will be released)

P.S. Apache HTTP server version 2.2 in CentOS 6 doesn't support SetHandler to proxy, but you can use the httpd24 collection from [SCL repository](https://wiki.centos.org/AdditionalResources/Repositories/SCL). I also recommend you to upgrade to a more recent CentOS version, 6 being very old and close to end of life.

Comment: Thanks for your response and info. I decided to roll it back to 5.6 in the end end and will just build a new server on CentOs 7 and attempt to set this all up on there.